# Is there an interface that specifies that an argument (a collection) can be indexed by an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, list, data-structures, interface

I am trying to use an OrderedDictionary as an argument for the below extension function (by the way if you think `collection.Reverse().Where(i => predicate(i)).Take(n)` would be better, let me know!), but the generic OrderedDictionary implementation I use (based on [this version](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericOrderedDictionary.aspx)) does not implement IList.

The collection only needs to provide access to its elements with an integer-based index (which OrderedDictionary does).

Is there another way to specify this requirement, without creating an overload?

```
/// <summary>
/// Return n elements, starting from the end of collection, that satisfy predicate.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="collection"></param>
/// <param name="predicate"></param>
/// <param name="n">Max number of elements to return</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> LastBefore<T>(this IList<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate, int n) {
    if (collection == null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }
    for (int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        if (n == 0) break;
        if (predicate(collection[i])) 
        {
            --n;
            yield return collection[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest defining an IReadableList interface; were it not for the fact that a read-write indexer does not count as an implementation of a read-only indexer, such a thing could have been a parent of IList (IMHO, it should have been anyway).  Existing IList implementations won't implement IReadableList unless wrapped, alas, but having a read-only list interface would make the concept of covariance much more useful, since an IReadableList<Cat> could be used as an IReadableList<Animal>.

Incidentally, I tend to think that while IList<T> doesn't inherit from the non-generic IList, perhaps it should.  Any IList<T> could implement IList in type-safe fashion if the non-generic implementation is read-only.  Even if one never actually read any objects from the non-generic IList, implementing it would make allow a routine which wants an IEnumerable<Animal> but is given an IList<Cat> [which of course implements IEnumerable<Cat>, and thus implicitly IEnumerable<Animal>] to get a Count of the collection without having to enumerate it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the MSDN about type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), unfortunately not.

Best you can do it create [an interface that requires an indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkyhsw31%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but obviously you couldn't do that with built in classes (unless you defined a wrapper class just for that purpose).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) on any `IEnumerable<T>`.  For collections implementing `IList<T>`, this will use fast indexing rather than enumerating all elements up to the index requested.  This provides read-only access and also works with collections that don't have built-in indexing support, albeit with a performance penalty.  You would typically document the method to indicate that collections supporting indexing are preferable as the argument passed in.

If you need to provide read-write access, `IList<T>` is probably a reasonable constraint; if you need something limited to just the indexer, your best bet is to create a shallow wrapper class that encapsulates a provided `IList<T>`, but only gives an indexer to the consumer.